# "401: Bad credentials" Basic authentication through url in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, basic-authentication

I am trying to make a basic authentication with Spring security. I also want to make it through the url (username:password@mysite.com). The authorization headers are set correctly when I do an http request like this, also here is my SecurityConfig:

```
 12 @Configuration
 13 @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
 14 @EnableWebSecurity
 15 public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 16 
 17   @Override
 18   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 19     http.authorizeRequests()
 20       .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
 21       .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
 22       .anyRequest().authenticated();
 23     http.httpBasic();
 24     http.csrf().disable();
 25   }
 26 
 27   @Autowired
 28   public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
 29     auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
 30         .withUser("user").password("pwd1").roles("USER").and()
 31         .withUser("admin").password("pwd2").roles("ADMIN", "USER");
 32   }
 33 
 34 }
```

And here is my AdminController:

```
 24 @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
 25 @RequestMapping(value="/admin")
 26 @Controller
 27 public class AdminController {
154   @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
155   public  String admin(Model model) {
156     return Constants.ADMIN_TEMPLATE;
157   }
177 }
```

And when I try to make a request like:

```
admin:pwd2@localhost:3000/admin
```

I get "401: Bad Credentials". Why is this happening? (I also tried making a request with Authorization header through restclient with the same result)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Delete http.httpBasic(); and try again